# Как правильно согласовать?

Tags: согласование

Интересует такое предложение: "Какой мальчишка, а то и девчонка, не мечтал стать капитаном..." Честно говоря, затрудняет форма слова "мечтал". Как тут правильнее сказать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: > Как тут правильнее сказать?
> 

Странно и беспокойно порой видеть упорный акцент на форму (потому что слово отзовётся в умах сугубо содержанием).
Во-первых, далеко не каждый мальчишка мечтает или мечтал стать (каким-то) капитаном. А во-вторых, девочки в этой категории вообще исключения. В предложении же категорично утверждается противоположное. 
Перестроил бы предложение (хотя бы) так: *"Какой мальчишка (а были даже девчонки), не мечтал стать капитаном!"* Вместо многоточия возможен также знак вопросительный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше выбрать множественное число: "Какой мальчишка, а то и девчонка, не мечтали стать капитаном...". На выбор влияют следующие факторы: а) подлежащее стоит перед сказуемым; б) женский род второго подлежащего, непосредственно примыкающего к сказуемому.